# JSON response showing unsafe-inline error in Google DevTools?

Tags: json, http, google-chrome-devtools

I've made a Flask API, and recently applied Flask-Talisman for security management (headers).

When I try to make a request towards the route `ping` on my API I get (send) the response:

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

However, in Chrome DevTools it shows the error:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-4Su6...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

What I'm unsure of is if this is an actual error, or is this something that DevTools is trying to do that causes it? Does it think the JSON is somehow inline style?

My response header is: `x-content-security-policy: default-src 'self'`

An image of what I experience, and think maybe causes the problem:

[image: The error]

Comment: No, nothing about this minimal JSON should count as “inline style”. This probably comes from the next step, where your app tries to do something with/based upon that JSON response …?

Comment: @CBroe one would think so, but for this test I am in fact just calling directly towards the API in a browser tab. It is not wrapped in any HTML-page or similar for this test, so the only data being passed is the `{"success":true}`.

Comment: You mean, you are just requesting the API URL by directly putting it into the browser address bar? Then my guess would be this is due to something the browser does internally, like trying to convert/modify the response for display (think syntax highlighting for code or something like that.)

Comment: @CBroe yes, correct. I've added an image of what I now maybe think causes the issue. I guess the "Elements" tab wraps the response in HTML to present it, and thereby adding inline style, which gives the error. Thank you for your help.